# Why is fft-based convolution always running slower than spatial convolution?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, fft

I was trying to validate the Convolution Theorem to use it as a part of my project. I implemented a custom Keras layer for performing FFT-based convolution (Fourier_Conv2D()). But it was running slower than Keras Conv2D layer. I supposed this may be because the Conv2D layer's internal implementation is pretty optimised. Hence I also wrote another custom layer to perform spatial convolution in naive manner (Spatial_convolution()). But the fft-based layer runs slower than even this naive implementation. 
I see that fft-based convolution is faster only in case of large kernels. I tried using kernels varying from 3x3, 5x5, 7x7... to 19x19 on 28x28-sized images dataset (MNIST). The maximum time taken by a kernel size is 40ms per training step, whereas the fft-based method takes 60ms (Note that the time in fft-based method is independent of kernel size because I have initialized complex kernel of the size of the image in this method).

Here are the codes of the two layers -

```
FOURIER CONVOLUTION


class Fourier_Conv2D(Layer):
    def __init__(self, no_of_kernels, **kwargs):
        self.no_of_kernels = int(no_of_kernels/2)+1
        super(Fourier_Conv2D, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel_shape = (int(input_shape[1]), int(input_shape[2]), int(input_shape[3]), self.no_of_kernels)
        self.kernel_r = self.add_weight(name = 'kernel', 
                                      shape = self.kernel_shape, 
                                      initializer = 'uniform', trainable = True)
        self.kernel_i = self.add_weight(name = 'kernel', 
                                      shape = self.kernel_shape, 
                                      initializer = 'uniform', trainable = True)
        self.kernel = tf.complex(self.kernel_r,self.kernel_i)
        super(Fourier_Conv2D, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x):
        if(x.dtype=='float32'):
            x = tf.spectral.rfft2d(x)

        outputs = tf.TensorArray(dtype='complex64',
                   size=self.no_of_kernels,
                   element_shape=[None,self.kernel_shape[0],self.kernel_shape[1]])
        index = tf.constant(0)
        #loop_vars = [index, outputs]

        def condition(i, outputs):
            return i < self.no_of_kernels

        def body(i, outputs):
            op = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(x, self.kernel[:,:,:,i]), 3)
            return i+1, outputs.write(i, op)

        j, output = tf.while_loop(condition, body, loop_vars=[index, outputs])
        output = output.stack()
        output = tf.transpose(output, perm=[1,2,3,0])
        output.set_shape([None, self.kernel_shape[0], self.kernel_shape[1], self.no_of_kernels])
        print(output)
        return output

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], input_shape[1], input_shape[2], self.no_of_kernels)




SPATIAL CONVOLUTION


class Spatial_convolution(Layer):
    # Works for square images and kernels only

    def __init__(self, no_of_kernels, kernel_size, **kwargs):
        self.no_of_kernels = no_of_kernels
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        super(Spatial_convolution, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel_shape = (int(self.kernel_size[0]), int(self.kernel_size[1]), int(input_shape[3]), self.no_of_kernels)
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name = 'kernel', 
                                      shape = self.kernel_shape, 
                                      initializer = 'uniform', trainable = True)
        self.inputshape = input_shape
        super(Spatial_convolution, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x):
        k = int(self.kernel_size[0])
        n = int(self.inputshape[1]) #height=width
        self.outshape = n-k+1

        out = tf.TensorArray(dtype='float32', size=self.no_of_kernels, element_shape=[None, self.outshape, self.outshape])

        o = tf.constant(0)

        def bodyj(j, i, o, row):
            op = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(x[:,i-int(k/2):i+int(k/2)+1,j-int(k/2):j+int(k/2)+1,:], self.kernel[:,:,:,o]), [1,2,3])
            return j+1, i, o, row.write(j, op)

        def condj(j, i, o, row):
            return j < self.outshape

        def bodyi(i, o, col):
            j = tf.constant(int(k/2))
            row = tf.TensorArray(dtype='float32', size=self.outshape, element_shape=[None])
            j, i, o, row = tf.while_loop(condj, bodyj, loop_vars=[j, i, o, row])
            row = row.stack()
            row = tf.transpose(row, perm=[1,0])
            row.set_shape([None, self.outshape])
            return i+1, o, col.write(i, row)

        def condi(i, o, col):
            return i < self.outshape

        def bodyo(o, out):
            i = tf.constant(int(k/2))
            col = tf.TensorArray(dtype='float32', size=self.outshape, element_shape=[None, self.outshape])
            i, o, col = tf.while_loop(condi, bodyi, loop_vars=[i, o, col])
            col = col.stack()
            col = tf.transpose(col, perm=[1,0,2])
            col.set_shape([None, self.outshape, self.outshape])
            return o+1, out.write(o, col)

        def condo(o, out):
            return o < self.no_of_kernels

        o, out = tf.while_loop(condo, bodyo, loop_vars=[o, out])
        out = out.stack()
        out = tf.transpose(out, perm=[1,2,3,0])
        out.set_shape([None, self.outshape, self.outshape, self.no_of_kernels])

        return out

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.outshape, self.outshape, self.no_of_kernels)
```

Could anyone please suggest why it is happening this way?

Comment: The speed of the FFT depends strongly on the implementation, and on the image size. You might get different results for images different sizes. Also Keras is likely using the GPU for convolution but not for FFT.

Comment: Okay, thanks.. but I have taken fft of the images before the training starts, so the 'if(x.dtype=='float32'): x=tf.spectral.rfft2d(x)' condition never gets executed, and the kernel is initialised as complex valued directly rather than initialising a real-valued kernel and taking its fft. So in essence, the fft is not executed in the fft-based convolution, still it is slower than the spatial convolution.. I wonder why!

Comment: If you discount the 3 FFTs you normally compute for a convolution through the frequency domain (input image, input kernel, output image), then all you have left is a point-wise multiplication (with complex numbers, so 4 multiplications and 2 additions per pixel, but actually only half of that because of the symmetry). A 3x3 convolution in the spatial domain is 9 multiplications and 8 additions per pixel. You are saying that 2 MADs is taking significantly longer than 9 MADs? That makes no sense. You must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Yeah, even I am surprised how that's happening.. the fft code has a single loop and it processes complex numbers, while the spatial convolution code has three nested loops and it processes real numbers. The backpropagation part is left to the Keras backend which would train all the 'trainable'-declared weights in the network. Can it be the case that there's some difficulty in backpropagation in the fft code due to complex numbers etc., that is making the training slower?

Comment: Could Keras/TensorFlow experts tell if there is something inefficient about my way of coding or the data structures used, since I am not an expert in TensorFlow.. But both the codes are logically correct since these layers when plugged in the network preserve accuracy of the network..